# Problems encountered in changing a CRichEditCtrl selection color

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have written the following code after creating the CRichEditCtrl

// 06112010 : The following code was added to highlight the textselection in black color instead of the default blue color of CRichEditCtrl. - 1311

{

```
m_EditControl.SetSel(0,100);
CHARFORMAT2 cf1;
cf1.cbSize = sizeof(CHARFORMAT2);
m_EditControl.GetSelectionCharFormat(cf1);
cf1.dwMask = CFM_BACKCOLOR ;
cf1.dwEffects &= ~CFE_AUTOBACKCOLOR;
cf1.crBackColor = RGB(0,0,0);
m_EditControl.SetSelectionCharFormat(cf1);
m_EditControl.Invalidate();
```

}

After this I am adding text, but the selection still comes in blue color instead of Black.  Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong??
Thanks,
DeV

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using SetSelectionCharFormat, which will only reformat the selected text. What you're asking for is an owner draw rich edit control, which is going to be more work than just deriving your own custom window from CWnd and implementing your own WM_PAINT handler.